# Anaconda Prompt automatically opens with an environment activated (Windows)?

Tags: anaconda

I'm been having some weird issue:

```
(quant) C:\Users\Randy666>conda deactivate

C:\Users\Randy666>
```

Some while ago I created an environment named "quant". Now, when I launch anaconda, it automatically opens with this environment active, and even if I deactivate this environment, when I re-open anaconda prompt, it still opens with 'quant' being active. How should I fix this problem?

Comment: Can you check what your `Anaconda Prompt` shortcut has set as a `Target`?

Comment: how should I check the target?

Comment: Right click on Anaconda prompt shortcut->Properties

Comment: I think it's pointing to the path of the `quant` environment: ```%windir%\System32\cmd.exe "/K" D:\Softwares\Anaconda\Scripts\activate.bat D:\Softwares\Anaconda\envs\quant```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Anaconda prompt on windows is jsut a shortcut to the `cmd`. Yours was probably changed to activate the `quant` env automatically. Check the `Target` of the shortcut by simply `Right-click->Properties` on the `Anaconda command prompt` shortcut. My anaconda prompt has the target:

```
%windir%\System32\cmd.exe "/K" <path to anaconda or miniconda>\Scripts\activate.bat <path to anaconda or miniconda, i.e. the base env>
```

If you change the second path to any other env, then your anaconda prompt will automatically activate said env. To activate `base` instead, simply restore the path back to the base env.